# How to separate code to another functions in wordpress custom rest route callback?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom rest route in my wordpress:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'site', '/test-route', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'handle_webhook',
  ) );
} );
```

Everything worked perfectly fine but I'm making a refactor now and I'd like to change the previous code:

```
function handle_webhook( $request ) {
    
    //
    // processing
    //

    return new WP_REST_Response('Done, bro!', 200);
    die();

}
```

into:

```
function another_function_1( $request ) {
    //
    // processing
    //

    return new WP_REST_Response('Done from 1, bro!', 200);
    die();
}

function another_function_2( $request ) {
    //
    // processing
    //

    return new WP_REST_Response('Done from 2, bro!', 200);
    die();
}

function handle_webhook( $request ) {
    
    if ($something) {
        another_function_1( $request );
    } else {
        another_function_2( $request );
    }


    return new WP_REST_Response('Done, bro!', 200);
    die();

}
```

So in general I'd like to separate the code to another functions. The problem is that I'm always receiving the response from the main function (`'Done, bro!', 200`).

When I put the `return` to if statement it works:

```
if ($something) {
    return new WP_REST_Response('works here!', 200);
} else {
    return new WP_REST_Response('works also here when $something is !true', 200);
}
```

But from *another functions* I'm enable to return a response.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `function ()` :

```
function another_function_1( $request ) {
    //
    // processing
    //

    return new WP_REST_Response('Done from 1, bro!', 200);
    /** die(); */
}

function another_function_2( $request ) {
    //
    // processing
    //

    return new WP_REST_Response('Done from 2, bro!', 200);
    /** die(); */
}

function handle_webhook( $request ) {
    
    if ($something) {
        return another_function_1( $request ); /** Added return */
    } else {
        return another_function_2( $request ); /** Added return */
    }

    /** With the if {} else {} above, this code will never be reached.    
    /** return new WP_REST_Response('Done, bro!', 200); */
    /** die(); */

}
```

Otherwise, it just keeps moving on beyond the function call.

Also, there is no need to `die();` after a return, the code is mute, since the process never comes to that point in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```php
function handle_webhook( $request ) {
    
    if ($something) {
        $result = another_function_1( $request );
    } else if ($somethingElse) {
        $result = another_function_2( $request );
    } else {
        $result = new WP_REST_Response('Default', 200);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

> Because of the way HTTP and/or HTTPS works is that, you can only send one response (for one request), but you could use `JSON` array or something, to workaround that limitation and .